# The differential of the Gauss map of the Theta Divisor of a quartic plane curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let's suppose we have a non-hyperelliptic Riemann surface $X$ of genus $3$ (without lost of generality, embedded in $\mathbb{P}^2$ as a smooth plane curve) and we consider its Theta Divisor. Is well known that the Gauss Map of the Theta Divisor can be identified with the map which associates to the divisor $P+Q$ on $X$ the line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ spanned by those two points, and to the divisor $2P$ the tangent line to $X$ at the point $P$.

What about the differential of this map? What are the points of the Theta divisor for which the differential is not injective? Do they have a geometrical description?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Today, a colleague anonymously downvotes even well formulated questions like this one. I don't understand!

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: And sorry JeanMarie: where is the question you mean? There are a lot of thinks that I don't understand...

Comment: What I don't understand ? I don't understand the downvote that maybe you have not noticed because I have upvoted just after. Besides, it's difficult **for me** to understand your question because it's not my field of competence. I only see that there is a connection with groups on elliptic curves.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you mean. You say that is not your field, but seriously you make me really curious: in another context I've seen a connection with "groups on elliptic curves" that you meen. Only I don't see this connection here. Could you say me something more, or just where I can find more information on this topic? I would be really greatful.

Comment: I couldn't say that I see a true connection. I can only give you a reference of a powerpoint presentation that considers the continuous **and** the discrete case, the latter being rather central in modern cryptography. It is (http://www.howard.edu/csl/courses/cae-iae/lec-notes/sycs%20653/lecture_notes_10_fall%202009.ppt)

Comment: A very nice recent article concerning elliptical curves : (www.math.rug.nl/~top/Expos2015.pdf)

Comment: This is not exacly what I need, but in some cases one needs to hear the right word to get new ideas, and maybe this is one of those:) Thank you for your time!